# Android 11: avc: denied { read } for name="sdcard"

Tags: android-permissions, file-access, android-11

After upgrading to Android 11, access to my app’s files under `/sdcard/Android/data/<packageId>/files` is no longer possible. I get the following error:

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:672): avc: denied { read } for name="sdcard" dev="tmpfs" ino=6474 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_29:s0:c244,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mnt_sdcard_file:s0 tclass=lnk_file permissive=0 app=com.example.myapp
```

This behavior presists even after I request `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest and grant it to the app.

I understand that, even with maximum storage permissions, Android 11 [restricts access](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#operations-allowed-manage-external-storage) to certain paths, including `/sdcard/Android/data`. **However, the directory I am trying to access is the app’s own data dir.**

How do I get access to this path while using `File` and the like, rather than SAF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closer examination of the issue revealed that the app tried to access its own data dir through `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/<packageId>/files`. While (on my device) `/mnt/sdcard` and `/sdcard` are both symlinks pointing to the same target, apparently they are not created equal.

Removing the path setting, causing the app to fall back to the data dir as reported by the API, fixed things for me.

I ran some more tests and found the following:

- path as reported by the API: works
- `/sdcard/Android/data/<packageId>/files`: works
- `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/<packageId>/files`: does not work
- `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packageId>/files` (replacing `/sdcard` with its symlink target): works

It is also worth noting that the docs mention `/sdcard` specifically.

**Conclusion:** App access to their external private storage area depends on the path used. Different ways of addressing the same path may yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

I tried disabling hermes in build.gradle and it worked just fine.